# File upload progress bar with no server component?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

Is it possible, on any browser, to indicate the percent complete of a file upload without requesting that information from the server?

In other words, is there any browser which knows (in a javascript-accessible way) how much of a file it has uploaded?

Comment: yes I believe so. look at the new html5 changes....you can post files using ajax now, with progress. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/

Comment: I believe if you upload via ajax and the browser supports the progress event you would be able to hook that. It's still technically talking to the server to get the status, though.

Comment: Using [XMLHttpRequestUpload](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) to upload or flash uploader that uses ExternalInterface to call js functions.

Comment: I don't think so such a access is blessed with JS.

Comment: @user1090190 asker means without server interpretation

Comment: Here's another tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress

Comment: @AshokRaj The browser requests from server is (I'm assuming) held locally when JS calls a ref to it. It requires no extra work on server side for it to work other than a file upload form. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You can also use flash for older browsers http://swfupload.org/

Comment: @user1090190 hmm. I also would love such a mechanism if possible somehow, even if it takes to install a third party native code in my server!

Comment: does it work without server interpretation?

Answer (score 0):

Browser file uploads don't provide a scriptable handle for JavaScript.

Typically how this is done is via a an AJAX call to the server, which then passes back the data based on the **server's** file upload status (which can be scripted). I don't think this can be done on the client side alone.

Comment: This applies to pre-HTML5 browsers. HTML5 browsers support `onProgress` hook